# How to create matrix in matlab that adds cells horizontally

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, matrix

I want to create a matrix, for example, a 1xn, where n is determined by another input.
For example, I have the following:

```
Example = [3 5 7 9];
New_matrix =  [int_col(Example (1)) int_col(Example (2)) int_col(Example (3)) int_col(Example (4))];
```

This New_matrix is how I want my outputs.

However, for my actual data input, my Example matrix is 1x47. **How can I put this in a for loop so it gives the outputs of 1 to a specified number for all of the length Example?** (keeping it horizontal as well)

Help function I used is added here:

```
% Helper function added as well 
function v = int_col(n)
v = zeros(1,n);
for index=1:n
   val = randi(n);
   while (val == index || any(val == v))
       val = randi(n);
       if (index == n && (any(v == n) ~= 1))
           val = n;
           break
       end
   end
   v(index) = val;
   if (index == n && val == n)
%       v(n) = v(n-1);
%       v(n-1) = n;
   end
   if n == 1 
       v = 1;
   end
end
v = v';
v = (sortrows(v))';
end
```

Comment: According to your first example you just need [linear indexing](https://ch.mathworks.com/de/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html): `new_matrix = int_col(Example)`. The second part of your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to reimplement `randperm()` in `int_col()`? I'm not sure what the purpose of running `sortrows()` on each column separately is, but I guess this may be what you wanted:

```
% Make up vector of column lengths
Example=randi(60,[1 47]);

% Create matrix
New_matrix=nan([max(Example) numel(Example)]);
for i=1:numel(Example)
  New_matrix(1:Example(i),i)=randperm(Example(i));
end

% Sort matrix rows from left to right
New_matrix=sortrows(New_matrix);
```

Please note that all columns in a matrix must have the same number of entries, so you will need to pad shorter columns with some value; a typical choice is NaN, which is treated as a special value by `sortrows()` and some other functions.

~

If my guess is incorrect and you do mean your code as it currently is, you just need:

```
New_matrix=[];
for i=1:numel(Example)
  New_matrix=[New_matrix 1:Example(i)];
end
```

Changing the size of `New_matrix` on every iteration is generally not good practice, but for 47 iterations only this should be fine.